Create file geodatabase (.gdb) using free and open-source Python package
I am new to geospatial data analysis, and I would also use just free and open-source Python packages to work with.
Now I try to create geodatabase (.gdb),  but I can not find any appropriate Python package to do so, however there is some Python package to read .gdb files such as GDAL and Fiona as explained in this question but I am not sure (and can not find) any appropriate way to create a geodatabase (from scratch) using these packages.
Now my main questions are

Except ArcGIS (and ArcPy) is there any other package to create a geodatabase?
If the answer to question one is "YES", how can I create a geodatabase in Python?


The GDAL driver is read/write https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/openfilegdb.html.

"File geodatabase" isn't a file, it's a directory with scores to thousands of files. Creating a file geodatabase is trivial, and just gets you an empty container.

You're right, geodatabase is a directory, I will also edit it in my question text. But my main question is about creating a geodatabase whose content is some CSV files, and raster files together with point and polygon shape files.

The raster access with GDAL is read-only https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/openfilegdb.html#raster-openfilegdb. Are you forced to use some special ESRI tools, or could you just forget filegeodatabase and use free and open format like GeoPackage instead?

I'm general you should encourage your end users to switch to an open format rather than continuing to force proprietary lock in.

If the real question is about populating tables in the created file geodatabase (feature classes and rasters), then that should be the focus of the Question. Note that neither CSV files nor raster files are permitted in a FGDB -- the act of loading them changes the data into tables (which are only readable with tools that are file geodatabase aware, and even the Esri FGBD DLL doesn't support rasters). One exception is mosaic datasets, which reference the GeoTIFFs on disk where they reside.

I dont know about raster support, but you can create a file geodatabase by writing any table to it:
import geopandas as gpd
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(x=[1], y=[1]), crs=4326)
df.to_file(filename=r"C:\GIS\GIStest\a_new_database.gdb", layer="temptable", driver="OpenFileGDB")

Then you'll have to delete the table created.
